# RecyclerView does not change from 2 columns to 3 columns when phone is rotated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

RecyclerView does not switch from two columns to three columns when I rotate the view to landscape.  I tried this code:

```
mGLManager.setSpanCount(3);

mGLManager = (GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
mGLManager.setSpanCount(2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGLManager);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3) );
```

I also tried these lines to get it to refresh:

```
mRecyclerView.refreshDrawableState();

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

mRecyclerView.invalidate();

mRecyclerView.requestLayout();

mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(mRecyclerView.getAdapter(), true);
mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0,0);
```

Here is my current code.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // set the number of columns based on the orientation
        if( newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2));
            mRecyclerView.invalidate();
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if( newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ) {
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3));
            mRecyclerView.invalidate();
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The toasts demonstrate that the code runs when I flip the orientation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add inside your onCreateView method of Activity it will be called each time of an orientation change

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
 mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2));
}
else{
 mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I had to wrap it with an if block:

    if( mGLManager != null ) {
        // your code -- thanks!
    }

In addition, the onCreate method runs every time the phone is rotated so I had to update the onCreate method as well.

Thanks for your help!